# Help with the Minkowski space-time metric

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

I've been trying to learn how to multiply two tensors in order to go from
$$g_{\mu\nu} dr^\mu dr^\nu$$
to
$$c^{2}\,dt^2-dx^2-dy^3-dz^2$$
But I can't figure it out.
$g_{\mu\nu}$ is a $4\times4$ matrix, and after the tensor multiplication you get a scalar.

Can someone explain all the steps to me?

Comment: This link helps https://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/special-relativity/31-minkowski-metric

Comment: That’s not really tensor multiplication; it’s (double) contraction. When you multiply tensors (without contracting) you end up with *more* indices (a higher-rank tensor). Here you end up with *fewer*: a scalar.

Comment: If you try to think in terms of matrices and row or column vectors, what will you do when you encounter a tensor with three or more indices?

Comment: Keep in mind $g_{\mu\nu}, g^\mu_\nu, $ and $g^{\mu\nu}$ have different matrix representations. So you could get the wrong results if you use a matrix to do it and choose the wrong one.

Comment: Do you know the difference between one forms and vectors? It's very important to get the matrix representations of the contractions right. Often you have to actually use a transpose or the inverse of a transpose to get the matrix multiplication approach to work right.

Comment: I don't know what a one form is or at least I don't remember I probably had it in class but that was long ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are unaware of the use of [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) for brevity. In this case, we wish to perform a [scalar contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction): $$\sum_{\alpha, \beta}g_{\alpha \beta} \ dx^\alpha dx^\beta = \sum_{\alpha} \sum_{\beta}g_{\alpha \beta} \ dx^\alpha dx^\beta $$

Based on the result you want, the metric signature is $(+, -, -, -)$ ; so the corresponding metric tensor is: $$g = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

The off diagonal terms are all zero, so $g_{ij} = 0 \ \forall \ i \ne j$ $$\sum_{\alpha} \sum_{\beta}g_{\alpha \beta} \ dx^\alpha dx^\beta = g_{00} \ dx^0 dx^0 + g_{01}(...) + g_{02}(...) + g_{03}(...) \\+g_{10}(...) + g_{11} \ dx^1 dx^ 1 + g_{12}(...) + g_{13}(...) \ + \ [...]$$

It is clear that this reduces to: $$\sum_{\alpha} \sum_{\beta}g_{\alpha \beta} \ dx^\alpha dx^\beta = g_{00} \ dx^0 dx^0 + g_{11} \ dx^1 dx^1 + g_{22} \ dx^2 dx^2 + g_{33} \ dx^3 dx^3$$

Substitute $g_{00} = 1,\ g_{11} = -1,\ g_{22} = -1,\ g_{33} = -1$ and with $dx^0 = cdt,\ dx^1 = dx,\ dx^2 = dy,\ dx^3 = dz$, you get your desired result:
$$\boxed{\sum_{\alpha} \sum_{\beta}g_{\alpha \beta} \ dx^\alpha dx^\beta = c^2dt^2 - dr^2}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The expression $g_{\mu\nu} dr^\mu dr^\nu$ is shorthand for the following summation: $$g_{\mu\nu} dr^\mu dr^\nu=\sum_{i=0}^3\sum_{j=0}^3\  g_{ij}\ dr_i \ dr_j$$ where the expression on the right is written using more standard matrix indexing notation.

With $$g_{\mu\nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -c^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ and $$dr^\mu = \left(dt,dx,dy,dz \right)$$ we simply apply the above summation formula to obtain $$g_{\mu\nu} dr^\mu dr^\nu=-c^2 \ dt \ dt + 0 \ dt \ dx +  ... + 1 \ dx \ dx \ + ... + 1 \ dy \ dy + ... + 0 \ dy \ dz + 1 \ dz \ dz$$$$g_{\mu\nu} dr^\mu dr^\nu=-c^2 \ dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$